# Does seasonality frequency matter in exponential smoothing?

Tags: time-series, seasonality, exponential-smoothing

I'm pretty new to time-series forecasting and I hope that someone could help me out. Referring to Holt-Winters' multiplicative method in https://otexts.com/fpp2/holt-winters.html, how does frequency of time series affect the performance of the model's predictions? Specifically, is there a difference if I take m = 7 vs m = 365? If it does, then is there any situation where the predictions are the same for different values of m?

[image: Holt-Winters' multiplicative method]

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Hi: Yes, there's going to be a huge difference because in one case you are assuming that the seasonality is weekly and in the other case you are assuming that it is yearly. In the former, you are saying that observations that are 7 days apart have some special effect due to that particular day. So, there's a monday effect, a tuesday effect, a wednesday effect etc. In the yearly case, with m = 365, things don't repeat until the next year begins so the seasonality is based on the time of year. So, january 1 has its own effect, january 2 has it own effect, etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking the time to reply @mlofton. What if we always have the same kind of effect for the same day of the week? For example, suppose a store makes 20% more sales every Saturday over the last few years. Does taking m = 7 (looking at Saturday a week ago) result in the same or different prediction as m = 365 (looking at Saturday a year ago) under the different conditions: (1) No trend (2) Upward trend (3) Downward trend?

Comment: Hi: In the hw framework, the trend is independent of the season. The question is whether the seasonal is multiplicative or additive. In your case, it's assumed to be multiplicative. As to  your other question, when you use $m=7$, you are saying that every saturday ( or any other day such as sunday, monday ) has the same effect as it had the week before.  When $m=365$, you are saying that each day ( saturday, sunday, monday ) has the same effect as it had the year before. So, in the latter case, you are saying that there is a "day" effect that is specific to each individual day of the year.